# Mathematica 11.2 / 11.3 Startup error

Tags: warning-messages, kernel-startup

This is problem that I am finding since the last release of Mathematica version 11.2 and also in version 11.3. On starting up Mathematica I get the following three messages:

1) An unknown menu command token (MenuListCDFPreview) was encountered in the menu setup file MenuSetup.tr.

2) An unknown menu command token (DeployEmbedded) was encountered in the menu setup file MenuSetup.tr.

3) An unknown menu command token (DeployStandalone) was encountered in the menu setup file MenuSetup.tr.

Although, the message allows me to continue (with the warning that some features of Mathematica might not function properly) and I can ultimately open notebooks, the messages themselves are annoying.

Could anybody let me know how fix this issue and to get rid of these startup messages.

Comment: What do you get for ``CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "MenuConfigurationFile"]``? That's where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the MenuSetup.tr file and commented out the the lines that contain these command tokens (they had to do with Previewing and Exporting CDF files which I don't often use).

Comment: All you have to do is just run `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, MenuConfigurationFile->”MenuSetup.tr]`

Comment: This does not help. I think there is some issue with the commands: MenuListCDFPreview, DeployEmbedded, DeployStandalone, in my version of Mathematica.

Comment: The setup file you said you had isn’t on the default path. You may need to remove your current one but fundamentally that means you have a non-standard one with broken or futurists tokens.